# Best way to key a table that is unique on two attributes for perfromant joins in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, join, database-design, foreign-keys

I have a costs table that stores the cost of an item on a particular day. 
The table is as follows

```
===============================
id   item_id   cost_date   cost
===============================
```

Where id is the primary key, item_id is a foreign key to the items table, cost_date is the date the item was available, and cost is the cost of the item. I also have an orders table

```
==============
id  order_date   
==============
```

where id is the primary key and date is the date of order. The if an item was ordered on a particular day it should have cost entry where cost_date matches the order_date for the order it is part of.
Finally I have an orders_items table

```
==============================
id   order_id  item_id   price
==============================
```

where id is the primary key, order_id is the foreign key to orders, item_id is the foreign key to items and price is the price of the item in that particular order.

Often I want to look at price and cost together which leads to this nasty set of joins.

```
FROM orders_items
LEFT JOIN items ON orders_items.item_id = items.id
LEFT JOIN orders ON orders_items.order_id = orders.id
LEFT JOIN costs ON costs.date = orders.date AND costs.item_id = items.id
```

The fact that I have to do the double join for costs is really slowing down my queries. I am wondering if there is a way to change the keys that would allow for a set of joins that is more performant in the long run? 
Is there a good place to create a foreign key to costs.id which is unique for each row in costs and would remove the need for the double join?

Comment: Please show your table definitions including indexes.

Comment: `costs` needs `INDEX(date, item_id)` (in either order).  Or, perhaps it is already the PK?  The performance should not be too bad.

Answer (score 0):

The joins per se are not slowing you down. Your tables are appropriately normalized.

From how you are using your tables, pair (item_id , cost_date) is UNIQUE NOT NULL in Costs. Tell the DBMS.

Index your foreign key column sets and their referenced columns since you want fast joins on them: Items (id), Costs (id) & (item_id , cost_date) (in MySQL serving to index (item_id) & (cost_date)), Orders (order_date) and Orders_items (order_id) & (item_id). Note that you don't really need Costs id and Orders_items id since these tables/relationships have natural keys. MySQL automatically indexes PRIMARY KEYs.

Foreign key declarations make a huge difference because then the DBMS knows that when it finds a match there are no others. Indexes make a huge difference because they either avoid scans (hashed) or shorten them (sorted) and they can avoid accessing secondary storage.

Denormalizing introduces redundancy to be managed including extra code and computing on updates and can greatly increase the size of tables, increases the size of rows forcing data out of memoryaccess to secondary store. Just make the most straightforward design. Later identify the most effective places optimize and denormalize only after measurement and confirmation.

[MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual 8.3 Optimization and Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimization-indexes.html)

PS The most straightforward query here is to use INNER JOINs.